# Передача struct по ссылке box/unbox

Tags: c#, struct, unboxing

разбираюсь с box/unbox, просматриваю свой код на наличие операторов box через ildasm.exe

Вникая в литературу разобрался с самыми банальными вещами, но возник один вопрос на который не могу найти ответа, прошу объяснить.

```
class Program
{
    static ManagerMyClass ManagerMyClass = new ManagerMyClass();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        //first example
        MyClass myClassLink = null;
        ManagerMyClass.GetClassLink(ref myClassLink);
        var myStruct = new MyStruct(myClassLink.A);

        //second example
        var myStruct2 = new MyStruct();
        ManagerMyClass.GetMyStruct(ref myStruct2);
    }        
}

struct MyStruct
{
    internal readonly uint A;

    internal MyStruct(uint A)
    {
        this.A = A;
    }
}

class MyClass
{
    internal readonly uint A;

    internal MyClass(uint A)
    {
        this.A = A;
    }
}

class ManagerMyClass
{
    readonly MyClass MyClass = null;

    internal ManagerMyClass()
    {
        this.MyClass = new MyClass(1);
    }

    internal void GetClassLink(ref MyClass MyClass)
    {
        MyClass = this.MyClass;
    }

    internal void GetMyStruct(ref MyStruct MyStruct)
    {
        MyStruct = new MyStruct(this.MyClass.A);
    }
}
```

Верно ли, что при использовании метода `ManagerMyClass.GetMyStruct()` происходит невидимая упаковка переменной `myStruct2` и последующая распаковка? Или это работает иначе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Упаковка не производится, просто значение передается по ссылке.

> Не следует путать понятие передачи по ссылке с понятием ссылочных типов. Эти два понятия не совпадают. Параметр метода может быть изменен с помощью ref независимо от того, принадлежит ли он к типу значения или ссылочному типу. При передаче по ссылке упаковка-преобразование типа значения не производится.

https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref

Comment: скажите, а в этом случае ссылка указывает не на область памяти в куче, а на область в стеке?

Comment: Извините, не знаток таких подробностей. Для меня достаточно знать, что ref предоставляет возможность передать переменную типа значения по ссылке без упаковки, а следовательно, без затрат производительности на неё.

Comment: спасибо! скажите, а если метод будет возвращать `MyStruct` возникнет ли некоторая потеря производительности связанная с передачей не ссылки на объект а полного копирования?

Comment: Проверил на таком вот примере:  
static int MyMethod(ref int a) {  a = 20; return a; }  
если возвращаемое значение сохранять в переменную, то там оказывается копия значения, передаваемого ref-параметром в метод. Но я не думаю, что копирование последовательности байт (при адекватных размерах структур, разумеется) будет давать какую-то сильную нагрузку на ЦП. А вообще, я не понимаю зачем так сильно углубляться в вопрос потери производительности на упаковке/копировании, если доподлинно не известно, что проблема именно в этих моментах.

Comment: спасибо за Ваши комментарии